# Remove Password on Galaxy S4

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-4, password

I somehow set a password for my Galaxy S4 (Android v4.3). I cannot figure out how to remove the password. Where is the setting to do so? I have to enter the password anytime I want to unlock the phone from the lock screen.

Note: I know the password, I just need to turn off the password.

Comment: Is this a password you have to enter on the lock screen, to unlock the phone; or a password you have to enter when the phone boots; or something else?

Comment: @DanHulme - It is the password I enter on the lock screen to unlock the phone. I edited question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the main device Settings, and from the **My device** page, choose **Lock screen**. Click on the **Screen lock** item to see the list of screen lock methods, and change it to whichever type you like (perhaps **Swipe** or **None**). You'll have to enter the existing password (or PIN) to make the change.

If you're using your phone to connect to a corporate Exchange server, or similar, then a security policy on the device might force you to have a password (or possibly a PIN, depending on the policy). In that case, you'll have to speak to your network administrator to get the policy removed before you can remove the password.